# FT230xs USB basic UART converter dropping frames

Tags: pcb, stm32, usb-device, linux, ftdi

I'm working with a custom [STM32F429](https://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32f429-439.html) board, I am using serial-USB port (USART1-PA9,PA10) for debug output and diagnostics. When I connect the board the FTDI chip is recognized and proper kernel modules are loaded.

dmesg output:

```
[  260.406486] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  260.526558] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6015
[  260.526563] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  260.526567] usb 2-1.1: Product: FT230X Basic UART
[  260.526569] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  260.526571] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: DN4934JQ 
[  261.545819] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  261.545829] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  261.552062] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[  261.552086] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[  261.552266] ftdi_sio 2-1.1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[  261.552341] usb 2-1.1: Detected FT-X
[  261.552891] usb 2-1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

The problem is that when I use GTK terminal, putty, or moserial to view the datastream, the data is always jumbled up and has missing fields. For example `Helloworld\r\n` turns to `ellwold\r\n`. `Inited Can Bus at bitrate 125000 bps` turns to `Initd aus a birate 500 ps`. I have attached the relevant schematic here. I have basically copy-pasted the self-powered USB design from the datasheet for FT230XS.

[image]

You might notice that there are no decoupling caps on the VCC pin as shown in the datasheet. Connecting 2x 100nF and 1x 4µF caps on this pin was causing an error where the chip couldn't be read by the Linux kernel.

```
[ 4135.146806] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 45 using ehci-pci
[ 4135.226834] usb 2-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[ 4136.187078] usb 2-1-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

Also I have configured the CBUS0 pin for VBUS_SENSE via the FT_PROG utility. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly helpful as this is my first project with any FTDI chip.

Edit:

PCB design snapshot:

[image]

Comment: The same happens to me when I accidentally open the same Linux port twice. Another idea: are you sending each character as separate USB packets? That wouldn't be good.

Comment: And the connection from the FTDI chip to the ST? I'd expect to see some error messages in the log if the problem is on the USB side so I'd go hunting on the UART side. First try connect the RX and TX together and see if a loopback is working correctly, if that works, check what's wrong on the ST side of things.

Comment: @Arsenal: I'm pretty sure that the st side of things are fine since i tried with another off the shelf FT232RL module by jumping tx rx cables and it worked fine without any glitches.

Comment: @AndersPetersson: I'm not sure i follow, as i understand the entire usb protocol is handled on chip (FT230xs), i have no control over how the usb frames are formatted. My ST code however sends strings over the UART TX/RX lines.

Comment: My mistake. Then you could try with lower UART baud rate.

Comment: @AndersPetersson: Tried it at Baud 9600 8bits 1 Stop bit and no parity. Same result. I'll try replacing the chip and post the result

Comment: So i replaced the chip, altered the baud settings, tried different combinations of decoupling caps on the Vcc pin, changed the usb cable twice. The issue still persists. What to do next?

Comment: like @Arsenal pointed out. If it is an error related to usb side of things then this would show up in the dmesg log atleast as a warning. I think this is somehow related to signal integrity issues. I have edited the original question with the pcb design snapshot for reference. Please note that the tx and rx have been swapped on the pcb via jumpers. This was a design error. Rest all remains the same.

Comment: well signal integrity would mostlikely result into some garbage words but it looks like some are simply dropped instead. Did you try the loopback (connect FT's TX with its RX and disconnect ST's connections) mentioned by Arsenal? What was the outcome?

Comment: Did you check the tx output of stm32 with a scope? It could be that you're writing the data to stm32 usart port without checking that the previous symbol was actually sent out.

Comment: @ChristianB. I did the hardwired loopback method by removing ST connections and there is no echo. The scope shows no activity on the tx/rx line as well.

Comment: @ChristianB. The hardwired loopback method works now. Probably there was a soldering issue before. So the status is that the FT230xs side of things seem to work fine in isolation. STM32 UART also works as expected when connected to an off the shelf FT232RL module. Changing baudrates doesnt seem to fix the issue.